# Inserting a record into a table's ManyToMany field while using multiple databases

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm, multi-database

My project uses Django's builtin multi-database support and I am trying to synchronize data in 2 different databases by taking a record from one database and inserting it into another one.

I have tried to do this in the usual way using the *add* method of the [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add), but it did not work and did not insert the record in the intermediary table in the second db, but rather did that in the default db.

Here is how I did that:
I have a *Person* model which has a ManyToMany field to *Dbs* model:

```
...
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    tenant_dbs = models.ManyToManyField(to=Dbs, blank=True)
```

and Dbs model which contains a single column with the names of the databases a person can have access to:

```
...
class Dbs(models.Model):
    person_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,
                                 max_length=20
                                 )
```

So I want to get some Person, Dbs and intermediary records from the default database and copy them all to another database (let's assume its name is 'secondary'). So I do the following:

```
from core.models import Person
from .models import Dbs

#  here I take the objects from default db as I did not mention any other
#  db manually and save them in the 'secondary' db. This works fine and 
#  the records are duplicated to the db 'secondary'

p = Person.objects.get(pk='111')
p.save(using='secondary')
d = Dbs.objects.get(pk='some_db')
d.save(using='secondary')

# and now I retrieve the newly inserted records from the 'secondary' db and 
#  create a relation (insert a record into intermediary table, in other words)
#  using *add* method:
p2 = Person.objects.using('secondary').get(pk='111')
d2 = Dbs.objects.using('secondary').get(pk='some_db')

# **here is the problem: record is again inserted into default db
#  although it was retrieved from the 'secondary db'!**
p2.tenant_dbs.add(d)
```

I clearly see that no record is added to the table *person_tenantdbs* which was automatically created as the intermediary table on the database level in the 'secondary' db.

So I would like to know how to deal with that and insert a record into this table if the db is not default?

I already tried using manager as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases), like this:

```
...
p2.tenant_dbs.db_manager('secondary').add(d)
```

but it still does not work.

According to the Django source code, it seems like this method only takes the db provided by router in case of multi-db scenario, see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4122d9d3f1983eea612f236e941d937bd8589a0d/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L644):

```
db = router.db_for_write(self.model, instance=self.instance)
```

So, is there a way to insert it and manually assign the db, or this can only be done with the router exclusively?

I would like to ask for help with this and would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not because of adding many to many. You just forgot to use 'using' method.

You should change these

```
p = Person.objects.get(pk='111')
d = Dbs.objects.get(pk='some_db')
```

with

```
p = Person.objects.using('secondary').get(pk='111')
d = Dbs.objects.using('secondary').get(pk='some_db')
```